# How to import application.yml property in an annotation in dto class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Application.yml

```
 datetime:
      format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

transaction.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Transaction{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransactionSourceEnum transactionSource;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String transactionId;

    private String responseCode;

    private String failureReason;

    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date transactionCreSysDate;

}
```

I tried this

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "${datetime.format}")
```

It won't work. I want to replace the JsonFormat pattern with datetime.format

Comment: Does it give any errors ?

Comment: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: Perhaps without `@Vallue()` annotation you can't get a property value.

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution would be to use the property during the configuration of `ObjectMapper`.

In spring the simplest way to do that is to define value for the property

```
spring.jackson.date-format=${datetime.format}
```

The main drawback of this solution is that it only allows configuring one date format per application.
Because, as you noted, it is not possible to use SPEL inside `@JsonFormat` annotation. And it is also impossible to use non-constant fields in the annotation parameters. I don't think there is a simple solution that would allow for configuring date format with configuration property.

Answer (score 1):

When i had faced the same issue i just defined a Global Variable
`public static String date = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";`

and

change the pattern to use the global variable
`@JsonFormat(pattern = Classname.date)`

It did work to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
@Value("${datetime.format}")
private String dateFormat;

@JsonFormat(pattern = dateFormat)
```

Comment: `java: annotation not valid for an element of type java.lang.String` this error shows up when I do that

Comment: I don't think you can use instance fields as annotation parameters.

Comment: @PiotrSwiderski if you'll do that you'll get `error: element value must be a constant expression
    @JsonFormat(pattern = dateFormat)`